# Using mysql variables in many actions Symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I have a problem with getting access to the previously set mysql variable.

In the single controller method I do so:

```
public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        /* @var $connection Connection */
        $connection = $em->getConnection();
        $connection->executeQuery('SET @user_id = 1;');

        return [];
    }
```

However, in another one I would like to get this value:

```
public function listAction(Request $r)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        /* @var $connection Connection */
        $connection = $em->getConnection();

        var_dump($connection->executeQuery('SELECT @user_id;')->fetchColumn());exit;
    }
```

When dump in the same way and the same variable immediately after its creation, this value exists. I need this variable because I have a trigger in which I get this variable.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to achieve is almost impossible due to how mysql user define variables work.

> User-defined variables are session specific. A user variable defined by one client cannot be seen or used by other clients ... All variables for a given client session are automatically freed when that client exits

from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html

The exeptions to this is:

> (Exception: A user with access to the Performance Schema user_variables_by_thread table can see all user variables for all sessions.)

from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html

The two actions you presented in your example are two different php processes that don't usually share the mysql session, so they won't share the mysql user defined variable. I don't know what is your main objective but even if the variables were shared the script will not work properly if you have multiple users because there are scenarios in witch you variables will be overwritten by concurrent users eg:

> User with id 1 visits the indexAction and sets the variable @user_id to "1", User with id 2 visits the indexAction and sets the variable to "2". User with id 1 visits the the listAction and the variable will be "2" instead of "1".

I think you should reconsider you implementation. If you give me more info about your objective then maybe i can help with a some advises. Without knowing more details what it looks like you actually need, is to use the user session to pass variable between actions. something like this

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->get('session')->set('user_id', $id);
    return [];
}

public function listAction(Request $r)
{
    $this->get('session')->get('user_id');
}
```

Hope this helps,

Alexandru Cosoi